# How do I place the labels next to the series on a split packed bubble chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

### Issue

Using Highcharts I am trying to do away with the legend on a [split packed bubble](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/packed-bubble-split/) and place the series names under or near the visual groups (see illustration below).

[image: Illustration of labels on packed bubble charts series]

I tried setting [`plotOptions.packedbubble.label`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.packedbubble.label) to `{ enabled: true }` but its not showing anything.

### Question:

How do I show the series names under the groups of the split packed bubble chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `parentNodeFormat` feature or `parentNodeFormatter` callback to achieve the wanted effect. Using the callback you can return custom HTML element if you need.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j2hq9osz/

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    parentNodeFormat: '{series.name}',
    format: '{point.name}',
    style: {
        color: 'black',
        textOutline: 'none',
        fontWeight: 'normal'
    }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.packedbubble.dataLabels.parentNodeFormat

Comment: For anyone who wants to show only the parent labels without the small circle labels you can do `dataLabels: { format: '', parentNodeFormat: '{series.name}' }`